# monacaでファイル選択ダイアログを表示する方法

Tags: monaca, cordova

monacaにて、ローカルファイルを選択してパスを取得する方法がわかりません。
具体的には、端末にある音声ファイルを選択し、アプリに登録したいと考えています。

画像に関してはCameraプラグインという便利なものがありますが、
画像以外のファイルについては、同様のことをどのように実現すればよいでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

別の方法です．

`<input type="file">` を含むページを作れば，そこからファイル選択ダイアログが出せます．そこで選んだファイルを，このinput要素から何らかの方法で取得してやればよいはずです．

AngularJS なら，ngModel と類似した機能を持つ fileModel という以下のようなディレクティブを定義すれば，適当な変数にバインドできます．

```
app.directive('fileModel',function($parse){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            element.bind('change',function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    model.assign(scope,element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

（http://qiita.com/zaburo/items/f03433caa710902d599f から引用）

HTML側では，

```
<input type="file" file-model="src">
```

のようにすれば，`src`にfileオブジェクトがバインドされます．

Comment: 例えばMIME等を指定して、音声ファイルに限定する方法はあるだろうか？

Comment: `<input type="file" …>` を使うなら，accept属性を使えばできるようです．
http://momdo.github.io/html5/forms.html#attr-input-accept

Comment: これが、少なくとも Monaca x Android では効かないのだ...

Answer (score -2):

検証していませんが，こちらが参考になるかもしれません．
http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/file-chooser-dialog-for-phonegap-application/

Comment: 自力で実装するという方法ですね。
なるほど、ありがとうございます